# Setting custom CRS using PyQGIS

Tags: coordinate-system, pyqgis

I have a PyQGIS-script which reprojects to EPSG:25832. However, it needs some adjustments in the false_northing and false_easting parameters, therefor I tried to create a custom CRS with adjusted false northing and false easting.

However, even though I get no error, the new parameters doesn't seem to have any effect, as when loading the file in QGIS, it is still in its wrong position,  even though the custom paramaters are correctly overtaken in the .prj.

What am I doing wrong?

This is my script:

```
import qgis
import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()

# Create custom CRS by using prior defined offsets
wkt = 'PROJCS["ETRS_1989_UTM_Zone_32N",GEOGCS["GCS_ETRS_1989",DATUM["D_ETRS_1989",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",499924.5],PARAMETER["False_Northing",-172.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",9.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]'
out_crs = qgis.core.QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(wkt)
   


def reprojectShpFiles(inputfolderpath, outputfolderpath, crs):
    
    # Set filepaths
    main_path = inputfolderpath
    for filename in os.listdir(main_path):
        if 'shp' in filename:

            # Get filepath
            file_path = fr'{main_path}/{filename}'

            INPUT = file_path 

            OUTPUT = outputfolderpath+'/'+ filename 
            
            # Run reprojecting
            processing.run("qgis:reprojectlayer",
                          {'INPUT':INPUT,
                           'TARGET_CRS':crs,
                            'OUTPUT':OUTPUT
                           }
                          )

            print('OK')
            print('------')


shapefiles = r'path\to\inputfolder'
outfolder = r'path\to\outputfolder'

# Run function
reprojectShpFiles(shapefiles, outfolder,out_crs)
```

Comment: Generally there is a fast response to some question in this really great community. As there is still no response after almost a day, did I need to adjust my question more? Maybe something is unclear? Do I need to give more information?

Comment: What do you mean by *"doesn't seem to have any effect"*? Are you expecting to see a physical shift in the data after the new CRS is applied?

Comment: Hi @Matt Yes, when I load the data with the custom CRS in QGIS, it should be shifted to the correct location as defined in the CRS, but it is still in it's wrong position (even though the .prj is correctly adjusted with the custom parameters).

Comment: And another unexpected thing: When I open the relevant shape in QGIS, adjust the parameters manually in the .prj-file, then remove the layer from QGIS, and then loading the file again in QGIS, the parameters are correctly overtaken.

Comment: The layer and/or its coordinate system may be cached which is why removing/re-adding works.

Comment: Thank you, @mkennedy, I will try it out! At the moment I figured, that I may not have to adjust it manually, but it seems that the projection is not correct.